# Why Java ActionListener is not working?

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener

Folks, I intend to implement a simple button ActionListener but it appears to not work.
The java codes are attached as following.....
The program intends to respond the click action from user and change the context of the JLabel

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public JButton btn = new JButton("Click");
    public JLabel display = new JLabel("null");
    public JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

    public Frame() {

        mainPanel.add(btn);
        mainPanel.add(display);

        add(mainPanel);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == btn) {
            display.setText("it works");
            System.out.println("it works");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Frame testFrame = new Frame();
        testFrame.pack();
        testFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: u have to register the Button using btn.addActionListener(this);

Comment: At what point is the `ActionListner` attached to your button? Answer to this question yourself, and you'll know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your actionlistener (the JFrame itself) is not added with [addActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29).

Answer (score 7):

You should add ActionListner to the button

```
public Frame(){

    mainPanel.add(btn);
    mainPanel.add(display);
    btn.addActionListener(this);
    add(mainPanel);
}
```